# How are resolution and precision related?

Tags: terminology, definition, error-analysis

In a standard textbook (Ncert-11), it has been written that a measurement of 3.54 is less accurate but precise
and 3.7 is accurate but less precise (truevalue = 3.66). It seems that precision has been confused for resolution. can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy is how close it is to the actual value. Resolution is how how many decimal places you are reading, even if your reading is really far off from the true value.

Precision is how repeatable a reading is, which is not super explicit in any of your examples because it is related to multiple readings of a supposedly identical measurement. However, it is rather closely related to resolution because if you have more resolution you have more decimal places, and if more of those decimal places keep reading the same after taking identical measurements then you have higher precision (even if you are really far off from the true value).

But you can have high resolution and crappy precision where you are reading a lot of decimal places but they are all different each time you take a supposedly identical reading.

The assumption that resolution is synonymous with precision is the hope that people aren't making measurement instruments with really high resolution and crappy precision because that pretty much makes the extra resolution useless.